# Lock static variable - Timer and Event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, static, locking

I've a class with a method runs very X minutes and another method invoked a event handler. Both these will modify the status of static list.

Below is the code

```
 public class DatabaseOps
 {
  private static Timer timer = null;

  private static IDictionary<int, Model.Process> allProcessDetails = new Dictionary<int, Model.Process>();

  public DatabaseOps()
        {
          if (timer.IsNull())
            {
                timer = new Timer(5000);
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.AutoReset = true;
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        // Timer event
         private async void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var processDetails in tempAllProcessDetails)
            {
                // Some logic
                allProcessDetails.Remove(processDetails.Key); 
                await Task.Run(() => SendProcess(processDetails.Value));
            }
        }

        // Method invoked from event handler
        public void UpdateProcess(Model.Process processDetails)
        {

            if (!allProcessDetails.ContainsKey(processDetails.ProcessID))
            {
                // Add process to allProcessDetails
                // Some logic
            }
            else
            {
                // Modify existing process in allProcessDetails
                // Some logic
            }
        }
 }
```

The event handler method will check for process, it if it exists it will do some logic and if the process doesn't exists, then it will update the same process with new logic.

The timer will run every X interval and send the current status of every process to a external system and will remove the process from `allProcessDetails`.

Here I need to ensure the check code `allProcessDetails.ContainsKey(processDetails.ProcessID)` in `UpdateProcess` doesn't conflict with the remove code `allProcessDetails.Remove(processDetails.Key)` in `OnTimerElapsed`

As per my understanding adding a lock will block the access from another thread that is created using same code sequence but here the Dictionary is accessed by different thread that are created from different code sequence(timer and event handler)

So, how do I prevent the event handler method from accessing the same key which could be currently accessed in timer method for removing.

Comment: Do you really need to fire another `OnTimerElapsed` regardless of the previous `OnTimerElapsed` has finished executing? Also `System.Timers.Timer` (as well as `System.Threading.Timer`) is multi-threaded timer that means a callback is executed on a thread pool thread. So, knowing the above, why do you need `Task.Run` then?

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev  I do not want to wait for the task to complete before the next timer event. Also the logic implemented in the timer event before the Task.Run will not take more time than timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Just use *ConcurrentDictionary*:

```
 private static IDictionary<int, Model.Process> allProcessDetails = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Model.Process>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may simply use `ConcurrentDictionary`. It is a thread safe Dictionary It has the same constructor and the same `ContainsKey` method, but except `Remove` method you need to use `TryRemove` method.

Links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx